# Finding the constant c in the time complexity of certain algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort, insertion-sort

I need help finding and approximating the constant c in the complexity of insertion sort (cn^2) and merge sort (cnlgn) by inspecting the results of their running times.

A bit of background, my purpose was to "implement insertion sort and merge sort (decreasing order) algorithms and measure the performance of these two algorithms. For each algorithm, and for each n = 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, measure its running time when the input is

1. already sorted, i.e. n, n-1, …, 3, 2,1;
2. reversely sorted 1, 2, 3, … n;
3. random permutation of 1, 2, …, n.

The running time should exclude the time for initialization."

I have done the code for both algorithms and put the measurements (microseconds) in a spreadsheet. Now, I'm not sure how to find this c due to differing values for each condition of each algorithm.

For reference, the time table:

```
          InsertionSort                    MergeSort      
 n      AS    RS   Random              AS     RS    Random
100     12    419     231              192    191     211
200     13   2559    1398             1303   1299    1263
300     20    236      94              113    113     123
400     25    436     293              536    641     556
500     32    504     246               91     81     105
1000    65   1991     995              169    246     214
2000     9   8186    4003              361    370     454
4000    17  31777   15797              774    751     952
```

I can provide the code if necessary.

Comment: why not just go through your code/pseudocode/algorithm and perform a proper complexity analysis (instead of the usual "this is a good enough approximation")? Finding those constants from running times doesn't sound too fun/reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hardly possible to determine values of these constants, especially for modern processors that uses caches, pipelines, and other "performance things".

Of course, you can try to find an approximation, and then you'll need Excel or any other spreadsheet.

Enter your data, create chart, and then add trendline. The spreadsheet calculates the values of constants for you.

Comment: I didn't think of using Excel. Is there anyway to change the "logarithmic" trendline from using natural log to log2? Regardless, glad I asked here!

Comment: If spreadsheet doesn't provide the specific trendline, you can use additional scale with values n^2 or n*log2(n), and build linear trendline.

Answer (score 2):

First some notes:

1. **you have very small `n`**

   The algorithm complexity start corresponding to runtime only if `n` is big enough. For `n=4000` is `~4KB` of data which can still fit into most of **CPU CACHE's** so increasing to at least `n=1000000` can and will change the relation between runtime and `n` considerably !
2. **Runtime measurement**

   for random data you need the average runtime measurement not single one so for any `n` do at least 5 measurements each with different dataset and use average time from all

**Now how to obtain `c`**

If program has complexity `O(n^2)` it means that for big enough `n` the runtime is:

```
t(n)=c*n^2
```

so take few measurements. I choose last 3 from your insert sort, reverse sorted because that should match the worst case `O(n^2)` complexity if I am not mistaken so:

```
c*n^2   =t(n)
c*1000^2= 1.991 
c*2000^2= 8.186 
c*4000^2=31.777
```

solve the equations:

```
c=t(n)/(n^2)
c= 1.991/ 1000000=1.991 us
c= 8.186/ 4000000=2.0465 us
c=31.777/16000000=1.9860625 us
```

If everything is alright then the `c` for different `n` should be relatively the same. In your case it is around `2 us` per element but as I mentioned above with increasing `n` this will change due to **CACHE** usage. Also if any dynamic container is used then you have to include complexity of its usage to the algorithm which can be sometimes significant !!!

Answer (score 2):

First to understand is, that **complexity** and **running times** are not the same and maybe does not have very much to do with each other.

The **complexity** is a theoretical measurement to get an idea of how an algorithm slow down on *bigger* inputs compared to smaller inputs or compared to other algorithms.

The **running time** depends on the exact implementation, the computer it is running on, the other programms that run on the same computer and many other things. You will also notice, that the running time will slow down if the input is to big for your cache, and jump an other time if its also to big for your RAM. As you can see for n = 200 you got some weird running times. This will not help you finding the constants.

In cases where you don't have the code, you have no other choise to use the running times to approximat the complexity. Then you should use only big inputs (1000 should be the smallest input in your case). If your algorithm is deterministic, just input the worst case. Random cases can be good and bad, and so you never get anything about the real complexity. An other problem is, that the complexity measures "operations", so evaluating and `if`-statement or incrementing a variable is the same, but in running time an `if` needs more time than an incrementing something.

So what you can do is to plot your complexity and the values you measured and look for a factor that holds...

E.g. This is a plot of `n²` skaled by `1/500` and the points from your chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the case of 4000 elements and divide the time by the respective complexity estimate, 4000² or 4000 Lg 4000.

This is not worse than any other method.

For safety, you should check anyway that the last values align on a relatively smooth curve, so that the value for 4000 is representative.

As others commented, this is rather poor methodology. You should also consider the standard deviation of the running times, or even better, the histogram of running times, and cover a larger range of sizes.

On another hand, getting accurate values is not so important as knowing the values of the constants is not helpful to compare the two algorithms.